# Eigenfunctions of subgroup of Heisenberg matrices

Tags: group-theory, ergodic-theory, characters, eigenfunctions

Consider the subgroup of the Heisenberg matrices given by:

$$ \mathcal{S} = \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & z \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} : z \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N} \Big\}   $$
If we take a group rotation given by
 $$T(g) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \pi/4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \cdot g   $$
then I wish to find the eigenfunctions of $T$. According to theorem 3.5 of Walters' "Introduction to Ergodic theory" every eigenfunction is a multiple of a character. But I'm unsure how to use this theorem to back out the characters and eigenfunctions.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \pi/4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$, then it is easy to see that $T$ has only one eigenvalue: $1$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Ok so from that then we have that the eigenvalues of $T$ are given by $1 = \gamma(a)$ where $a$ is the matrix above and $\gamma$ is the character right? I'm unsure how to back out what the character function actually is from that. Is it a determinant of some kind? I guess I'm just confused about the character stuff itself as my background is more in analysis.